# Webservice response - do we need to return specific error code?

Tags: c#, json, rest

Instead of having an error code for each and every application error.

Why not simply return basic http code such as

```
422 Unprocessable Entity
401 Unauthorized
```

then you would identify the specific error in the body

```
[
  {
    "error": {
      "object": "user",
      "property": "email",
      "message": "email address is required"
    }
  }
]
```

Is there going to be any problem with this?

Comment: 500 is a server error. Would that work?

Comment: you can handle only those errors witch you know .. you can't handle those errors that you not have idea about it .. E.g Undamaged code

Answer (score 0):

Certain statuses may cause unintended side effects depending on where the request is made from. For example, returning a 401 to a browser prompts the user for a username/password. If you're expecting to make the service public or if you don't have a specific client in mind, make sure the status code is specifically for the situation you're intending to use it for.

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct way to do it. Just make sure you follow the HTTP specs to ensure you are returning the correct HTTP status code, and that you follow the spec as to what should be in the response body (e.g some of the response codes require that you have a solution in the body to the problem)